# TPL5111 to power ESP8266 12-F on 3xAA

Tags: timer, esp8266, battery-operated, ldo

I am trying to make use of the low power watchdog TPL5111 to facilitate an ESP8266 12-F for a 3xAA driven sensor project.

I thought it would be smart to enable the LDO enable pin (CE) by the TPL5111 DRV out. Apparently I missed something, as below circuit does not work as expected.

*Expected* behavior:

- TPL5111 powers the ESP8266 every approx 8min (with R1 & R2 values of 100 kOhm each).
- As EN/ONESHOT is high, TPL5111 is supposed to switch it off at same
  intervals unless DONE input signal received earlier (either triggered
  by manual DONE switch or ESP8266 GPIO14 (=stable during boot)
  output).

*Showed* behavior:

- TPL5111 never powers up the LDO. Changing R4 to 1 kOhm doesn't help.
- However, manual drive (M_DRV) switch and manual done (DONE) switch work reliably (blinking script on ESP8266).
- Manual starting (M_DRV) and waiting for the timeout does not work as
  expected: In 4 tested cases it switches the LDO unreliably off after
  approx 4min (run 2x, while R4=100kOhm) and approx 7min (run 2x, while
  R4=1kOhm).
- Manual starting (M_DRV) and power off by ESP8266 DONE (modified
  blinking script) works reliable.

Not sure how to proceed and where to modify next - any ideas would be appreciated.

LDO: [SSP7603](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1912111437_Shanghai-Siproin-Microelectronics-SSP7603P33M5R_C411031.pdf)

WD/Timer: [TPL5111](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/tpl5111)

Battery Power: 4.3V

[image]

Comment: I see that you have a BME280. Do you want to transmit regularly the data of this CI? The ESP-12 can enter regularly in "deep sleep" for a long time battery. And it could do all the tasks you want.

Comment: See this https://docs.ai-thinker.com/_media/esp8266/docs/esp-12f_product_specification_en.pdf  "Power Consumption:/deep sleep" page 11.

Comment: Coming originally from an ESP8266 breakout board with onboard LDO, I guess deep sleep was not very resource efficient and unfit for battery operation. Leaving that out brings it to an acceptable consumption of 20 microamps during deep sleep (vs 2 microamps TPL5111). Throwing in again permanently powered LDO with low quiescent current of approx 30 microamps and some NPNs to cut sensors plus 1/16th of 300mA Esp8266 active consumption brings us to about 0.1mA total, which could be very affordable for battery projects.

Comment: But still I don't understand why TPL5111 is not able to enable LDO here? I tought DRV of TPL5111 is exactly for this purpose (something like a high switch).

Comment: Ok. Hum ... I think there is a little problem. DONE is an input wired to GPIO14 ... which is an output. And you have a switch to force input to V3.3. You should use a 2k-10k resistor between GPIO14 and DONE & DONE-switch. R4 seems too high. What happens when you wire directly DRV to Battery? A pull-up 1k resistor should be used?

Comment: No information about CE pin of LDO? R4 should be 0?

Comment: Agree, R4 is probably still too high. I did now do R4=0. Still not self starting. Manual operation works. Regarding CE, it is enabling when high, float or gnd disables it - confirmed by manual testing. Regarding GPIO14 resistors, you might be right, but this part works (switching off LDO). Could you explain your suggestion to wire DRV to Battery? I don't see why I should do it, as it is an output.

Comment: Checking the Specs on TPL5111 it is mentioning at the section of digital logic levels, that the logical output HIGH level VOH (DRVpin) is VDD-0.3V@ 100uA and VDD-0.7 @ 1mA. Why should there be so high currents as I expect LDO CE something like a high switch? Maybe level is too low for LDE CE? How to check that or how to mitigate it?

Comment: Wiring (manually just for test) DRV to Battery (with R4=100k present) is to be sure that the  TPL5111 is well enabled, just to check. GPIO14 resistor just also to be sure that output GPIO14 is not damaged when pulsing "DONE-switch" (GPIO14 wired directly to 3.3V, problem if output level is "low").

Comment: DRV to Battery enables LDO immediately. But no self-start next time. Added LED (with 1 kOhm resistor) on 3.3V side. Observe a very short flash at timing cycles (when TPL5111 supposed to enable). Removed also all capacitors but without C3 it LED flickers constantly very dim. Maybe LDO CE pin is not working properly. Added 10k on GPIO14 to protect it.